# When might Spring Cloud Finchley.M3 be released to evaluate Spring 5 and Reactor 3.1?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

Does anyone have a coarse estimation when Finchley.M3 will be available, so that the latest versions of Spring (Boot) and Project Reactor can be tested and evaluated? Next week? Still in October? Probably November? Any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the spring-cloud-release [milestones](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/milestones) on Github.